# How to get N days ago in Dart's DateTime?

Tags: dart

There's the `subtract()` method but the documentation says it's not aware of daylight savings which makes it pretty much useless in this case, or in any other case except where the programmer doesn't know how many milliseconds there are in 24 hours.

I'm thinking of two ways:

get the day of the month, and then subtract N from it and if it's less than 1 then subtract the month and the year if appropriate and set the day for the last day of whichever month it turns out to be

OR

subtract N days from the noon of the current day and then get start of the day for the resulting day

Is there some easier/better way to do this?

Comment: Why not convert both `DateTime`s to UTC before subtracting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably try to convert both DateTimes to UTC (standardize), then call difference(). That converts it to a nice, easy Duration, which you can convert as necessary to hours, days, months, or whatever else.

```dart
DateTime one = somedatetime.toUtc();
DateTime two = someotherdatetime.toUtc();
Duration diff = one.difference(two);
//Then just convert...
return diff.inDays;
```